# Remove pseudo-duplicates from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with duplicates with the only one field that differs and have to clean up them, it looks like:

```
id1 | some_name    | some_details

id2 | some_name    | some_details

id3 | some_name    | some_details

id4 | another_name | another_details

id5 | another_name | another_details

id6 | another_name | another_details
```

... etc.

Could someone help with proper SQL script that delete duplicates and leave, for example, the following:

```
id1 | some_name    | some_details

id4 | another_name | another_details
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: GROUP BY col2, col3

Comment: Once you're done, don't forget to add appropriate unique constraints to the table so you don't have to do this job again. Don't just mop the floor, fix the leak.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the matter is we get this data using cron job from Redis as-is

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name we use MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To `select`, simply do a `GROUP BY`, use `min()` to get first id for each group:

```
select min(id), col2, col3
from tablename
group by col2, col3
```

To `delete` unwanted rows, simply do a `GROUP BY`, use `min()` to get first id for each group:

```
delete from tablename t1
where exists (select 1 from tablename t2
              where t2.c2 = t1.c2 and t2.c3 = t1.c3
                and t2.idcol < t1.idcol)
```

I.e. delete a row if another row with same col2 and col3 exists, but that row has a lower id value.

Comment: thank you for quick response! basically I need to delete duplicates, how to use your approach in such case?